# A meta box (in a custom post type) with two different type of fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox

[image]

I want to make a meta box (in a custom post type) with two different type of fields:

- Text
- and select, (maybe put it in array ?)

and display this meta box with this two fields with a single ID like so:

```
if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'The_ID', true ) != '' ) {
    echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'The_ID', true );
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you save the contents of the two input fields into one post_meta value you are able to call them at once.

**In the `save_post` action**

```
$text = esc_attr( $_POST['text'] );
$select = esc_attr( $_POST['select'] );

// saves the value as "text select"
$combined = trim( sprintf( '%1$s %2$s', $text, $select ) ); 

update_post_meta( $post_id, 'The_ID', $combined );
```

**Get Post Meta**

```
if ( $the_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'The_ID', true ) )
    echo $the_id;
```

An other way you can do this is by adding all the information in a serialized array and then save this.

**In the `save_post` action**

```
$text = esc_attr( $_POST['text'] );
$select = esc_attr( $_post['select'] );

$combined = serialize( array(
    'text' => $text,
    'select' => $select
) );

update_post_meta( $post_id, 'The_ID', $combined );
```

**Get Post Meta**

```
if ( $the_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'The_ID', true ) )
    $the_id = unserialize( $the_id );
```

`$the_id` will contain an array with the values of `text` and `select`.

Comment: Mike, the "text" and "select" must have the same ID and I must to put it in array? I do not understand.
I don't know how to put them in array.

Comment: Oh, you want to add everything in an array and then make it available. I edited my answer for you.

Comment: I tried to do this as it is in the picture, but it doesn't work. [see this link](http://m.uploadedit.com/b010/1361205537790.txt)  What i am doing wrong?

Comment: The result is this: [see here](http://s18.postimage.org/9vxjzi43d/the_result.png)

Comment: Could you provide us the whole script you use to display your metabox?

Comment: Here is the entire code for meta boxes: [see this link](http://m.uploadedit.com/b010/136137446339.txt)